# MySQL error in PHP edit.php script

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting a warning error in PHP for an edit.php script I'm creating for a database. When I click and go to the edit screen, it shoots out an error to me: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /../edit.php on line 34. Line 34 is the code that reads `if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)` If anybody can give me a solution to this error, I'd appreciate it.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/connection.inc.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Edit Record</h1>
    <p>Edit the tree!</p>
    <?php $id = $_GET["id"]; ?>
    <form method="POST" role="form" action="leaferie.php?flag=1&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php $dbc = dbConnect('read'); ?>

        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM trees WHERE id = $id");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
                { 
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="treeName">Tree Name</label>
                        <input name="tree_name" value="<?php echo $row["tree_name"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="treeName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="scientificName">Scientific Name</label>
                        <input name="scientific_name" value="<?php echo $row["scientific_name"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="scientificName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="plantType">Plant Type</label>
                        <input name="plant_type" value="<?php echo $row["plant_type"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="plantType">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="leaf">Leaf</label>
                        <input name="leaf" value="<?php echo $row["leaf"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="leaf">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="flower">Flower</label>
                        <input name="flower" value="<?php echo $row["flower"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="flower">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fruit">Fruit</label>
                        <input name="fruit" value="<?php echo $row["fruit"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="fruit">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="hardiness">Hardiness</label>
                        <input name="hardiness" value="<?php echo $row["hardiness"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="hardiness">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="culture">Culture</label>
                        <input name="culture" value="<?php echo $row["culture"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="culture">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="size">Size</label>
                        <input name="size" value="<?php echo $row["size"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="size">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="uses">Uses</label>
                        <input name="uses" value="<?php echo $row["uses"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="uses">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                        <input name="notes" value="<?php echo $row["notes"] ?>" type="text" class="form-control" id="notes">
                    </div>
                <?php 
                } 
                ?>
    <a href="leaferie.php?flag=2">View Records</a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: You need to handle the case of a `false` result from `mysqli_query()` before just assuming the query worked and trying to determine the number of rows returned.

Comment: As Mike Brandt said, your query is failing, figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($sql == FALSE) {echo mysqli_error(); exit;}
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {//do your thing
}
```

Obviously its an issue with mysqli not returning anything valid... so check the errors and all should become clear.